# Обязательно ли использовать шаблонизаторы в  PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день, взялся за написание более-менее крупного проекта. Изучил несколько основных паттернов MVC, ActiveRecord.....

Стал вопрос в выборе шаблонизатора,из интернетов понял что люди делятся на 2 типа, те кто говорят нужно использовать Smarty (плюшки кэширвоание, роутинг и т.д.) и прочее и те, кто утверждает, что PHP от части и сам шаблонизатор поэтому в иных не нуждается...

Но мешать PHP + html не очень хорошо, так сказать "г*вн*код". Хотел бы спросить у опытных разработчиков.

Ибо код вроде .... мне и самому не нравится...

```
 <?php foreach($all_users as $user) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $user['fio']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $user['office']; ?></td>
                            <td><span class="label label-alert">...</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                     <button class="btn btn-small"><span class="awe-refresh"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: это скорее дело религии, по собственному опыту могу сказать, что использование того же Twig в проектах для меня большое удобство, по крайней мере наследование шаблонов это мега удобно. И, как бы, высказывание о PHP как о шаблонизаторе немного устаревает, честно говоря

Comment: Я так ни разу смарти и не воспользовался, но по отзывам он лежит ровно посередине между чистым PHP и Twig. На Twig же я нарадоваться не могу и рекомендую использовать именно его (по крайней мере попробовать).

Comment: по мне так говнокод это и есть шаблонизаторы, вместо <?php echo $t;?> пишу просто <?= $t ?>

Comment: @Валентин Жуков, *да, вечно непонятно что там в этих шаблонах понаписано. Такое нагромождение!*

Comment: Простой пример нагромождения в twig:
<?php htmlspecialchars($var) ?>
vs
{{ var|e }}

Comment: Прошло 5лет от последнго комента, но вопрос там же.
Так значит, все эти Шаблонизаторы нужны для програмистов а не для сайта? Для удобства "верстальщика".
Я делаю сайт для себя, большой и мощный... тогда получается надо "гавнокодить" на чистом PHP и HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Основных причин две.
Все нормальные шаблонизаторы предлагают из коробки **автоэкранирование** и **наследование**.

В приведенном примере `<?php echo $user['fio']; ?>` рано или поздно приведет к XSS.
при использовании Twig, дефолтный оператор вывода, `{{ user.foo }}` автоматически устранит эту уязвимость.

Все примеры шаблонизаторов на чистом РНР кончаются на простых примерах вывода нескольких строк из базы. Но иногда у сайта бывает дизайн, общее для всех страниц оформление. Которое на чистоп пхп делается инклюдами, но потом вдруг на одной странице требуется подключить дополнительный яваскрипт... и шаблон превращается в спагетти. В нормальных шаблонизаторах есть наследование от основного шаблона, с возможностью переопределять или дополнять определенные блоки.